# codeigniter URL ReWrite error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I got a website done by a freelancer now he is missing and I don't know how to fix this.

This is my problem, I uploaded the script to website root (www.lanka.deals) but the problem is it rewrite index to /deals/ (www.lanka.deals/deals/) but I need to make it as (www.lanka.deals) edited base URL in Application/config/config.php still nothing.

Here is my htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

if any more information needed please tell me I will post them.

Answer (score 0):

**CodeIgniter .httaccess code recommendation :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
    # slashes.
    # If your page resides at
    # http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
    # then use
    # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it helps.

> **EDITED**

If your `base_url` is : `http://www.lanka.deals/`, then your `RewriteBase` is just slash : `/`

But if your `base_url` is : `www.lanka.deals/deals/`, then your `RewriteBase` should be : `/deals/`

It's all depends from how to you access your site from the URL (CodeIgniter `base_url`)

Comment: when it set to "RewriteBase /deals/" it shows me a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: thank you for the answer. but it still points to "www.lanka.deals/deals", I want to make it "www.lanka.deals" so badly :(

Comment: @DreammediaRulz Check your `base_url` and your `.htaccess`. Please rate up and checklist my answer if that is helped you :)